# How to access the data from a promise which is an object property

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following array of objects

```
const people = [
  {
id:'John:1:Aries',
exp:40.3,
scores: [4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 5],
futureScores:Promise.resolve([5, 5, 6]),
  },
  {
id:'Jane:2:Pisces',
exp:57.6,
scores: [6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6],
futureScores:Promise.resolve([4, 5, 6]),
  },
  {
id:'Tom:3:Leo',
exp:30.3,
scores: [4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
futureScores:Promise.resolve([4, 4, 6]),
  },
  {
id:'Amy:4:Sagittarius',
exp:35.0,
scores: [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5],
futureScores:Promise.resolve([6, 5, 6]),
  },
];
const extractId = (people) => {
return people.filter((person) => {
    const id = person.id;
    if(id.includes("a")){
      return person;
    }
})

}
const scores = extractId(people);
const avg = (scores) => {
  const getavg = scores.map((el) => el.scores.reduce((a,b) => a +b , 0)/el.scores.length);
  const allavg = getavg.reduce((a, b) => a+b/getavg.length, 0)
return allavg;
  }
```

I want to access the futureScores property and record the scores in another variable
Tried the following

```
const future = (scores) => {
  const arr = [];
  const fscore = scores.map((el) => {
      
     const fscores = el.futureScores;
    const result = fscores.then(function(value){
      
      console.log(value);
      arr.concat.value;
    });
    return  result
  })
  
  return fscore;
}
console.log(future(scores));
```

The first console.log is outputting the scores but console.log(future(scores)) is outputting [ Promise {  }, Promise {  } ]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's how you're handling promises within a map. The idea is you should return a map of promises and resolve them. Something like this:

```js
const future = (scores) => {
  return scores.map((el) => {
    const fscores = el.futureScores;
    return fscores.then((value) => value);
  })
}

Promise.all(future(scores)).then(res=> {
  console.log(res)
})
```

The idea is to return `fscore` which is a single promise but since it's a map, at the end we have an array of promises which we can resolve with `Promise.all`

I did away with arr.concat.value since you're not using it. And if you want to actually change the array, do `arr = arr.concat.value;` since concat does not mutate the original array, makes a new one.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that it was something simple but I just could not see it.

Comment: @retro I think people upvote or accept answers if they helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I know but as you can probably see my reputation is insufficient "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the array inside of the map function.

```
const future = (scores) => {
  const arr = [];
  const fscore = scores.map((el) => {
      
    const fscores = el.futureScores;
    const result = fscores.then(function(value){
      
      console.log(value);
       return arr.concat.value;
    });
    return  result
  })
  return fscore;
}
future(scores).forEach( val => {
  console.log(val)
})
```